# Weird behavior,Item in ListView auto-scale when scrolling?

Tags: android, user-interface

This is the normal:

[image: This is the normal]

This is the weird,when I scroll the listview some item shrinked(But the value of width and height did not change.):

[image: some items zoom-out]

In this screenshot item[1:3] is same kind,but item[ 3] didn't scale. which item scaled seem randomization maybe base the device or content.

The code of ListView and Adapter is nothing special :

```
mListView = new ListView(mContext);
mListView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
mProviderAdapter = new ProviderAdapter();
mListView.setAdapter(mProviderAdapter);


class ProviderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCount;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mProviders.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return mProviders.get(position).mMsgSpace;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 10000;
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return mProviders.get(position).getUI().getView();
        }

    }
```

the screenshot of Hierarchy Viewer(Lower Right Corner):[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvvKX.png)
[image]

and here is the custom views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#44FFFFFF" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/word"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#EC5800"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pron"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/definition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/add"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sound"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/audio"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/audio"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/switch_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/audio"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/definition"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Login" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/blank"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ViewAnimator>
```

another view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ViewSwitcher1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/example_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/example_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/example_zh_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/example_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/example_zh_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/switchto_note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/note_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/note_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/comfirm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

Comment: Could you post the xml code of the ListView en custom Row?

Comment: Do you really have 10000 different kind of view?

Comment: 10000 is probably magic value :) Better return IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE in getItemViewType().

Comment: getViewTypeCount have to return the number of types of Views that will be created by this adapter. So if you do not need 10000 views let 's getViewTypeCount the exact number of view type do you need

Comment: What is mProviders ? And how it is set ?

Comment: thanks! mice, you are right , why don't you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mice 's comment will fix the problem.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE
}
```

because this problem cause by the listview's recycle mechanism(a little more complicated ,I'm still learning,Can't explain more :( )

more accurate is the view's cache mechanism.

But It can't explain the weird scaling.

After more test, I finally find the weird scaling is a compatibility problem.
add `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>` to AndroidManifest.xml will fix it .

why?

```
Display display = getWindowManager()
        .getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
View v  = getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT);
String s = "DisplayMetrics:"
        + getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
        + "\nview : "
            + v.getWidth()+"*"+v.getHeight()
            + "\nscreen:" + width + "*" + height;
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

So if didn't add the `android:minSdkVersion`, View.[buildDrawingCache(boolean autoScale)](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/java/android/view/View.java#L6533) will return the wrong cache bitmap,that's why the weird scaling happend.

btw:return 10000 or any other values in the getViewTypeCount didn't make sense. because I found the system never call it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misusing `getViewTypeCount`

Delete the following methods from your adapter

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 10000;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (position);
}
```

If you want the first item on your list to look different use `addHeaderView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)` on your `ListView` instead of using types.

Comment: I believe getViewTypeCount() refers to how many different views your listview will house. ex.) in a chat application you may have to different chat bubbles, one for messages you send, and one for messages sent to you. In which case I believe the getViewTypeCount should return 2. getItemViewType() would then be used to help recycle views by telling the listview which viewType is used at a position. ex.) return 1 for a message sent to you, return 2 for a message you sent.

Comment: That's correct @Zachary but for the OPs example he didn't need types of views, yet he declared 10000 view types, which is clearly not the proper use for it.

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't require those functions to be overloaded. I confused implementing the ListAdapter Interface where you must have these functions with sub classing the BaseAdapter where it's optional to override. As an alternative to removing the functions one could set the return of getViewTypeCount() to 1 and getItemViewType() to 0 which would solve the problem while maintaining the same structure and allowing different views to be mixed in.